# search on list with ionic and json

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm relative new in angularJs + ionic, i need to create a Search function in my list of options loaded with external JSON file. 
I got this in my template:

```html
     <ion-view view-title="Citys">
       <ion-content>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="friend in friends" href="#/sps/restaurante/{{friend.id}}">
              <img ng-src="{{friend.thumbnail}}">
              <h2>{{friend.name}}</h2>
              <p>{{friend.category}}</p>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
```

Also have this in my app.js file

```js
.state('sps.restaurantes', {
      url: "/restaurantes",
      views: {
        'rest-tab-sps': {
          templateUrl: "templates/sps-restaurantes.html",
          controller: 'FriendsCtrl',
          resolve: {
            allfriends: function(Friends) {
              return Friends.all(); }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .state('sps.restaurante-detail', {
      url: '/restaurante/:friendId',
      views: {
        'rest-tab-sps': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/sps-rest-detail.html',
          controller: 'FriendDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
```

Have This in My controllers.js file:

```js
App.controller('FriendsCtrl', function($scope, allfriends) {
  $scope.friends = allfriends;
})
App.controller('FriendDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,$cordovaDialogs,$ionicSideMenuDelegate, Friends) {
  $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false)
  $scope.friend = Friends.get($stateParams.friendId);
   
}) // Close Controller
```

And Finally i have this in my services.js file:

```js
App.factory('Friends', function($http, $q) {
var friends = [];
  return {
    all: function(){
      var dfd = $q.defer();
      $http.get("js/sps-rest.json").then(function(response){
        friends = response.data;
        console.log(friends);
        dfd.resolve(friends);
      });
      return dfd.promise;
    },
    get: function(friendId) {
       for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        if (friends[i].id === parseInt(friendId)) {
          return friends[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
});
```

this is my external JSON File:

```html
[
     {
       "id": 0,
       "name":"Restaurant 1",
       "thumbnail":"http://yanupla.com/apps/turismo/json/sps/rest/fogoncito.jpg",
       "category":"Comida Mexicana, Restaurante, Bar, Shows Nocturnos",
       "address":"1ra calle entre 15 y 16 ave, Barrio Suyapa, Blvrd Morazán",
       "phone":"2550-1289, 2550-1403",
       "website":"",
       "schedule":"",
       "bio":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam efficitur leo, at posuere lacus fringilla eu. In pellentesque neque eget justo vulputate, quis imperdiet magna egestas. Suspendisse at tincidunt elit, a ornare risus. Cras ut elit egestas, blandit tellus quis, consectetur neque. Aliquam ullamcorper, metus vel ultrices facilisis, lorem orci suscipit massa, vitae rutrum urna ante vel dui." 
     },
     {
       "id": 1,
       "name":"Restaurant 2",
       "thumbnail":"http://yanupla.com/apps/turismo/json/sps/rest/cebollines.jpg",
       "category":"Comida Mexicana, Restaurante, Bar",
       "address":"1ra calle entre 15 y 16 ave, Barrio Suyapa, Blvrd Morazán",
       "phone":"2550-1289, 2550-1403",
       "website":"http://www.cebollines.com",
       "schedule":"Lun- Jue: 7:00-23:00 | Vier-Sab: 7:00-24:00 | Dom: 7:00-22:00",
       "bio":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquam efficitur leo, at posuere lacus fringilla eu. In pellentesque neque eget justo vulputate, quis imperdiet magna egestas. Suspendisse at tincidunt elit, a ornare risus. Cras ut elit egestas, blandit tellus quis, consectetur neque. Aliquam ullamcorper, metus vel ultrices facilisis, lorem orci suscipit massa, vitae rutrum urna ante vel dui." 
     }
]
```

What i need is a function that i can call when i input a search option on top of my template list.

Comment: You search option would a search bar? If so, take a look on this  article it gives you a easy way to filter the results as you type: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Wow! Awesome, thanks a lot, it's really easy with AngularJs filter, this was helpful

Comment: I will put my comment as an answer and you can aceept it  if you want :)